In Game Maker's Toolkit's Unity Flappy Bird tutorial, fix the problem where score can potentially increase by one after bird dies
I came up with two solutions to this problem. I'm confused why one of them worked and one did not.
Solution that worked: bool gameIsOver == false used as condition for adding to score
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LogicManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int playerScore;
    public Text scoreText;
    public GameObject gameOverScreen;
    public bool gameIsOver = false;

    [ContextMenu("Increase Score")]
    public void addScore(int scoreToAdd)
    {
        playerScore += scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();
    }

    public void restartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    public void gameOver()
    {
        gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
        gameIsOver = true;
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PipeMiddleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LogicManager logic;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3 && logic.gameIsOver == false)
        {
            logic.addScore(1);
        }
    }
}

Solution that didn't work: birdIsAlive bool used as condition for adding to score. I don't understand why this did not work. Instead of it not allowing the score to increase when the game ended, it simply did not ever allow the score to increase, even when it should have.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BirdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    public float flapStrength;
    public LogicManager logic;
    public bool birdIsAlive = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && birdIsAlive)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * flapStrength;
        }
        if (transform.position.y > 20 || transform.position.y < -16)
        {
            logic.gameOver();
            birdIsAlive = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        logic.gameOver();
        birdIsAlive = false;
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PipeMiddleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LogicManager logic;
    public BirdScript birdScript;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3 && birdScript.birdIsAlive == true)
        {
            logic.addScore(1);
        }
    }
}


just guessing; did you implement some kind of logic to set gameIsOver=false when the game restarts? are you missing that for birdIsAlive? (totally likely that I'm wrong and there's a different cause, I don't know unity)

Did you properly assign PipeMiddleScript.birdScript like you did with logic?

You can try firining an event, and then checking in logic, and check there if gameIsOver = false

Your problem may be in this line here:
public bool birdIsAlive = true;

This will serialise the value into the inspector and will use the inspector's value not the value written here when initialising the script.
If you first wrote,
public bool birdIsAlive;

Then saved the file,
Then wrote:
public bool birdIsAlive = true;

then the default value of false would have been assigned in the inspector and will overwrite this true value.
To fix this simply set the value to true yourself in code and consider using private variables for internal state.
void Start()
{
    birdIsAlive = true
    logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicManager>();
}

